# How to start windows service for a windows server using UI Action?

Tags: servicenow, cmdb

I want to start window service by clicking on UI Action which is on the windows server detail page so as below mentioned what i tried so far,

As a SNOW dev i have created one UI action called "Start service" and added in windows server detail screen (added that button because i want to start all windows services which is associated to this windows server)

Problem is i am not sure how to start that service using that button (Is there any specific code to start that services ?)

Please suggest what i have to do in this case !!

Comment: have you setup any orchestration workflows to communicate with the window services?

Comment: @3nigma, No i don't

Comment: https://www.servicenow.com/products/orchestration.html this might help